# Replacing the String containing Date and Time with Double Quotes prefixed with =(Equal Sign)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, replace, str-replace

Whenever writing the date-and-time to an excel sheet the default cell format treats it as date and time and display in the format
`dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`, rather than displaying as `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`

But coming back to an Excel Sheet, whenever the date and time is enclosed with `" "`(double quotes) and prefixed with `=`(equals sign), it treats it as a string holding some values and displays exactly as it is rather than displaying default `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` format.

So as per the requirement, to achieve the string containing table data having `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` format
need's to replace the date and time enclosed with double quotes with `="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"`

Eg: `25-Feb-2020 15:27:58` need to be replaced with `="25-Feb-2020 15:27:58"`

```
<table>
   \n        
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th style=\"\">
            <div class=\"th-inner \">Login Name</div>
            <div class=\"fht-cell\"></div>
         </th>
         <th style=\"\">
            <div class=\"th-inner sortable\">Registered</div>
            <div class=\"fht-cell\"></div>
         </th>
         <th style=\"\">
            <div class=\"th-inner \">Registered Date <br>Time</div>
            <div class=\"fht-cell\"></div>
         </th>
         <th style=\"\">
            <div class=\"th-inner sortable\">User Response Count</div>
            <div class=\"fht-cell\"></div>
         </th>
         <th style=\"\">
            <div class=\"th-inner \">Test Start Date Time</div>
            <div class=\"fht-cell\"></div>
         </th>
         <th style=\"\">
            <div class=\"th-inner \">Test End Date Time</div>
            <div class=\"fht-cell\"></div>
         </th>
         <th style=\"\">
            <div class=\"th-inner \">Time Remaining</div>
            <div class=\"fht-cell\"></div>
         </th>
         <th style=\"\">
            <div class=\"th-inner \">User Status</div>
            <div class=\"fht-cell\"></div>
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr data-index=\"9\">
         <td style=\"\">njuser14</td>
         <td style=\"\">Yes</td>
         <td style=\"\">-</td>
         <td style=\"\">0</td>
         <td style=\"\">25-Feb-2020 15:27:58</td>
         <td style=\"\">25-Feb-2020 15:28:03</td>
         <td style=\"\">179</td>
         <td style=\"\">Paused</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index=\"10\">
         <td style=\"\">njuser15</td>
         <td style=\"\">Yes</td>
         <td style=\"\">-</td>
         <td style=\"\">0</td>
         <td style=\"\">25-Feb-2020 15:27:32</td>
         <td style=\"\">25-Feb-2020 15:27:42</td>
         <td style=\"\">179</td>
         <td style=\"\">Paused</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

In the below coding snippets `BatchDetails` holding string containing table data, needs to be replaced and later assigned into session

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static string PersistBatchDetails(object BatchDetails)
{
    try
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["DashboardBatchInfo"] = BatchDetails;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){}
    return "S001";
}
```

---

Tried writing the code using [DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZMlZoF)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string text = "<table>\n  <thead><tr><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner \">Login Name</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner sortable\">Registered</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner \">Registered Date <br>Time</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner sortable\">User Response Count</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner \">Test Start Date Time</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner \">Test End Date Time</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner \">Time Remaining</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner \">User Status</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr data-index=\"9\"><td style=\"\">njuser14</td><td style=\"\">Yes</td><td style=\"\">-</td><td style=\"\">0</td><td style=\"\">29-Feb-2020 15:27:58</td><td style=\"\">29-Feb-2020 15:28:03</td><td style=\"\">179</td><td style=\"\">Paused</td></tr><tr data-index=\"10\"><td style=\"\">njuser15</td><td style=\"\">Yes</td><td style=\"\">-</td><td style=\"\">0</td><td style=\"\">29-Feb-2020 15:27:32</td><td style=\"\">29-Feb-2020 15:27:42</td><td style=\"\">179</td><td style=\"\">Paused</td></tr></tbody></table>";
        string text2 = " dasd arew 2017-03-11 12:25:56 2017-03-11 12:25:56 das tfgwe 2017-03-11 12:25:56 ";
        string pattern = @"\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}";
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
        var res = r.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(ConvertDateFormat));
        var res2 = r.Replace(text2, new MatchEvaluator(ConvertDateFormat));
        Console.WriteLine(res);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(res2);
    }

    static string ConvertDateFormat(Match m)
    {
        var mydate = DateTime.Parse(m.Value);
        return mydate.ToString("=yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    }
}

// 29-Feb-2020 15:27:58 need to be replaced with ="29-Feb-2020 15:27:58"
```

**Results:**

```
<table>
  <thead><tr><th style=""><div class="th-inner ">Login Name</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th style=""><div class="th-inner sortable">Registered</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th style=""><div class="th-inner ">Registered Date <br>Time</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th style=""><div class="th-inner sortable">User Response Count</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th style=""><div class="th-inner ">Test Start Date Time</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th style=""><div class="th-inner ">Test End Date Time</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th style=""><div class="th-inner ">Time Remaining</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th style=""><div class="th-inner ">User Status</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr data-index="9"><td style="">njuser14</td><td style="">Yes</td><td style="">-</td><td style="">0</td><td style="">29-Feb-2020 15:27:58</td><td style="">29-Feb-2020 15:28:03</td><td style="">179</td><td style="">Paused</td></tr><tr data-index="10"><td style="">njuser15</td><td style="">Yes</td><td style="">-</td><td style="">0</td><td style="">29-Feb-2020 15:27:32</td><td style="">29-Feb-2020 15:27:42</td><td style="">179</td><td style="">Paused</td></tr></tbody></table>
-------------------------------------------------------
 dasd arew =2017-03-11 12:25:56 =2017-03-11 12:25:56 das tfgwe =2017-03-11 12:25:56
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: [DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tlK21d)**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string text = "<table>\n  <thead><tr><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner \">Login Name</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner sortable\">Registered</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner \">Registered Date <br>Time</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner sortable\">User Response Count</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner \">Test Start Date Time</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner \">Test End Date Time</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner \">Time Remaining</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th><th style=\"\"><div class=\"th-inner \">User Status</div><div class=\"fht-cell\"></div></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr data-index=\"9\"><td style=\"\">njuser14</td><td style=\"\">Yes</td><td style=\"\">-</td><td style=\"\">0</td><td style=\"\">29-Feb-2020 15:27:58</td><td style=\"\">29-Feb-2020 15:28:03</td><td style=\"\">179</td><td style=\"\">Paused</td></tr><tr data-index=\"10\"><td style=\"\">njuser15</td><td style=\"\">Yes</td><td style=\"\">-</td><td style=\"\">0</td><td style=\"\">29-Feb-2020 15:27:32</td><td style=\"\">29-Feb-2020 15:27:42</td><td style=\"\">179</td><td style=\"\">Paused</td></tr></tbody></table>";
        string text2 = " dasd arew 29-Mar-2020 12:25:56 29-Mar-2020 12:25:56 das tfgwe 29-Feb-2020 12:25:56 ";
        //string pattern = @"\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}";
        //string pattern = @"\d{4}\-^[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}";
        //string pattern = @"\d{4}\-([JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JULY|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC])-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}";
        string pattern = @"\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}|\d{2}\-[a-zA-Z]{3}\-\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}";

        Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
        var res = r.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(ConvertDateFormat));
        var res2 = r.Replace(text2, new MatchEvaluator(ConvertDateFormat));
        Console.WriteLine(res);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(res2);
    }

    static string ConvertDateFormat(Match m)
    {
        var mydate = DateTime.Parse(m.Value);
        //return mydate.ToString("=yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        return string.Format("=\"{0}\"", mydate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    }
}

// 29-Feb-2020 15:27:58 need to be replaced with ="29-Feb-2020 15:27:58"
```